# Python list comprehension- compare 3 lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, list-comprehension, ifs

I am new to list comprehension. Currently I understand it when comparing two lists, but now that I am comparing 3, I'm a little confused. Basically I have this list:

`teams= ['subteamA', 'subteamB']`
these 2 teams are compared to an csv file that basically just alternates between subteamA and subteamB. My list comprehension is this:

`teamDimensions_semantic = [[ 1 if paramTeam == thisTeam else 0 for paramTeam in mySubteams] for thisTeam in teams]`

`print(teamDimensions_semantic)`

and then the output is something like [1,0,1,0,1,0] which works.

My question is now, how do I do the same thing, but with 3 teams in the list comprehension? I changed my teams to
`teams= [subteamA, subteamB, subteamC]`
now and changed the csv file to reflect that as well. But now I want my teamDimensions_semantic to look something like [1,0,2,1,0,2,1,0,2].

How do I write that in the list comprehension lines now? I'm getting stuck on the if's and else's.....any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Don't use nested list comprehensions with `if`. Use `index()` to get the position in the `teams` list.

```
teamDimensions_semantic = [teams.index(s) for s in mySubteams]
```